# Validation of my proof for: Every $T_2$ space is also a $T_1$ space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I made a proof for the following exercise and I was hopping that someone would check weather this is correct or not, and maybe tell me how I can Improve my proof and My proof writing skills in general.

---

#### The problem:

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be an Hausdorff Space ($T_2$ Space). Prove that $(X,\tau)$ is also a $T_1$ space.

So, this are the definitions that my textbook gave for $T_2$ and $T_1$ space and this are the definitions That I'll be using:

> A Topological space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be Hausdorff if for any $a,b \in X$ such that $a \neq b$, there exists $A, B \in \tau$ such that $a \in A$, $b \in B$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

> A topological Space $(X,\tau)$ is said to be an $T_1$ space if for every $x \in X$, the set $\{x\} $ is closed.

---

#### My proof:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a Hausdorff space.

Then, let $x,a \in X$ with $a \neq x$. Let's fix a value for $x$ and let $a \in X \setminus\{x\}$.

Then: $\forall a \in  X \setminus\{x\}, \exists U,U_a \in \tau: x \in U$ and $a \in U_a$ and $U \cap U_a = \emptyset$.

Because $U \cap U_a = \emptyset$, then $x \notin U_a$, but $\forall a \in X\setminus \{x\}, a \in U_a$, so we have that: $$X \setminus \{x\} = \bigcup \limits_{a \in X\setminus \{x\}} U_a$$.

Because $U_a \in \tau$ then $\bigcup \limits_{a \in X\setminus \{x\}} U_a \in \tau$, thus $X \setminus \{x\} \in \tau$.

So we conclude that for all $x \in X$ the set $\{x\}$ is closed in $(X,\tau)$, thus proving that $(X,\tau)$ is a $T_1$ space.

---

Is my proof valid? And, is there anything That I can improve in my proof?

Comment: Your proof seems correct. An equivalent definition of $T_1$ spaces is that for every $x,y \in X$, with $x \neq y$, there exist $U_x , U_y \in \tau$ such that $x \in U_x , \ y \notin U_x$ and $y \in U_y , \ x \notin U_y$. Using this definition, it is obvious that every $T_2$ space is $T_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s correct and understandable, but it could be written up just a little more smoothly, for instance something like this:

> Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be a Hausdorff space, and let $x\in X$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff, for each $a\in X\setminus\{x\}$ there are $U_a,V_a\in\tau$ such that $a\in U_a$, $x\in V_a$, and $U_a\cap V_a=\varnothing$. Clearly $x\notin U_a$, so $U_a\subseteq X\setminus\{x\}$. Let $U=\bigcup_{a\in X\setminus\{x\}}$; then $U$ is open, and $$X\setminus\{x\}\subseteq U\subseteq X\setminus\{x\}\,,$$ so $U=X\setminus\{x\}$, and $\{x\}=X\setminus U$ is closed. Since $x$ was an arbitrary point of $X$, it follows that $X$ is $T_1$.